# how does assembler convert from assembly to machine code?

Tags: c++, assembly, intel, processor

I know this has been asked many times, but I am looking for a simple interpretation.

Let's say I have some assembly code that C++ compiler generated.

Now assembler kicks in and it has to transform the assembly code into machine code.

**Question 1).** Will the C++ assembler compiler look at the table where each assembly instruction has the corresponding machine code instruction ?

**Question 2).** If the C++ program runs on the intel processor, then, assembler needs to take a look at the table published by Intel team, right ? because in the end, C++ program runs on the intel processor.

**Question 3).** If I am right about the question 2, then how is it possible that program written in C++ can be run on the computer which uses Intel and on the computer which uses AMD processor ?

Comment: Intel and AMD both use the same instruction set architecture, which defines what all the machine code means.

Comment: x86 or AMD64 depending on 32bit or 64bit.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86

Comment: Although most modern C++ compilers (MSVC, GCC, Clang) won't generate assembly, and go direct from internal representations to machine code.

Comment: Is there a chance that I might be using other than Intel/AMD and so that C++ program wouldn't run on my computer because of that ?

Comment: Do you have an Apple M1, Raspberry Pi, chromebook, android/apple tablet or Phone? Then you are probably running an ARM processor of some sort: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ARM_architecture And then yes you would need to compile the program to ARM machine code.

Comment: Thanks, understood. about 32bit and 64bit, I guess, when compiler starts to run, we tell it which bit system to use while compiling our source code, right ?

Comment: yes. though most default to whatever you are currently running on.

Comment: Is there a chance that 32 bit compiled machine code (c++ program) will run on 64 bit processor computer ? and vice versa  ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227542/discussion-between-user1937198-and-giorgi-lagidze).

Comment: @GiorgiLagidze -  There are other CPU manufacturers than Intel/AMD.   A fair few of those other platforms have compilers that target them - either from the vendor or a port of a toolchain such as gcc or clang.   As long as there is a compiler targeting a platform, and your code doesn't rely too much on specific features of particular hardware, your C++ program can probably be built and run on multiple platforms.    C++ isn't inherently a language that targets x86.   If you write code for specific platforms, then your code will need modification to run on other platforms.

Comment: please one question per question. Also from the comments it looks like a [xy-problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Maybe we can help you more when you ask for the actual problem you are trying to solve "I want to compile Code X for target architecture Y, but I encountered Problem Z"

Comment: @Peter, yes, but let's say I wrote a c++ program on my pc. my compiler created machine code from it depending on the specific set instructions published by the parent set of (Intel/AMD).  If this C++ program now runs on different CPU, which is not a child of the same parent set(Intel/AMD), then this program won't run on that CPU. do I make sense ?

Comment: I will ask the new one now so it's better organized.

Comment: DONE - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65793154/how-can-a-program-written-in-c-be-run-on-multiple-cpu

Comment: thats more or less the same question. Nicely reworded, but essentially same question. Why not edit this one?

Comment: you said to ask one question only, and you should understand that what i am trying to answer can't be just asked like in 2-3 words only.

Comment: I am just saying that you could have [edited this question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/65792675/edit). I don't expect it to be answered in its current state anyhow (I might be wrong though, but also then you don't need two of them). Nevermind, just trying to help

Comment: ....and I was proven to be wrong ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please try to limit your questions to one question per question.  Neverthless, let me try and answer them.

### Question 1

An “assembly compiler” is called an “assembler.”  Assembly is *assembled,* not *compiled.*  And the assembler is not specific to C++.  It is specific to the architecture and can only be used to assemble assembly programs for that architecture.

Yes, assemblers are usually implemented by having a large table mapping instruction mnemonics to the operation codes (opcodes) they correspond to.  This table also tells the assembler what operands the instruction takes and how the operands are encoded.  There can be multiple entries for the same mnemonic if the mnemonic corresponds to multiple instructions.

It is however not a requirement to do it this way.  Assemblers may chose different approaches or combine tables with pre- and postprocessing steps.

### Question 2

This is correct.  Processor vendors generally provide documentation for their processors in which all instructions and their instruction encodings are listed.  For Intel, this information can be found in the [Intel Software Development Manuals](https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/articles/intel-sdm.html).  Note that while the processor vendor provides such specifications, it is the job of the assembler author to translate these documents into tables for use by the assembler.  This is traditionally done manually but recently, people have started automatically translating manuals into tables.

### Question 3

Both Intel and AMD produce processors of the amd64 (also called x86-64, IA32e, Intel 64, EM64T, and other things) architecture.  So a program written for an Intel processor generally also runs on an AMD processor.

Note that there are tiny differences between Intel's and AMD's implementation of this architecture.  Your compiler is aware of them and won't generate code that can behave differently between the two.

There are also various *instruction set extensions* available on some but not all amd64 processors.  Programs using these will only run on processors that have these instruction set extensions.  However, unless you specifically tell your compiler to make use of such extensions, it won't use any of them and your code will run on amd64 processors of any vendor.

Answer (score 3):

> Will the C++ assembler

There is no "the C++" assembler. An assembler generally doesn't need to know anything about a higher level languages (if any) that were compiled to the assembly code.

> ... look at the table where each assembly instruction has the corresponding machine code instruction ?

Nothing says that there has to be a "table" but sure, an assembler supporting multiple CPU architectures could do that.

> If the C++ program runs on the intel processor, then, assembler needs to take a look at the table published by Intel team, right ?

Such table would likely be written by the authors of the assembler program rather than the CPU vendor. It would be based on manuals published by the vendor.

> how is it possible that program written in C++ can be run on the computer which uses Intel and on the computer which uses AMD processor ?

Intel, AMD and VIA all make CPU's that implement the same(ish) instruction set called x86-64. An assembler targeting x86-64 instruction set should work on CPU's that support x86-64 instruction set.

There are a few small variations between the different implementations, and the assemblers (and compilers) must be designed in a way to take such differences into consideration if the program is to work on all those systems. Example: Early Intel64 CPU's lack the NX bit (according to wikipedia, which doesn't cite a source). A program that is to work on those CPU's mustn't use that feature.

Comment: Other examples include https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86-64#Differences_between_AMD64_and_Intel_64.  That doesn't cite a source for its bullet point that early Intel64 CPU's lack the NX bit.  That's weird, because https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NX_bit#x86 says Intel implemented XD / NX in "later iterations of the Prescott (P4) core."  (Which were Intel's first x86-64 CPUs, including Nocona).  It's doubly surprising because x86-64 uses the same page-table format as PAE, and Intel added 32-bit mode XD support for PAE page tables at presumably the same time.

Comment: Hmm, another section of the same wiki page (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86-64#History_2) talks about steppings / revisions of Prescott and when XD / NX was implemented.  It seems to indicate that some Nocona (server) cores were sold based on a revision that had EM64T enabled but without NX support.

Comment: @PeterCordes Wikipedia is where I sourced my example. With a few further searches, I found no credible sources (as in Intel documentation). Only other mentioning it is a forum [post](https://lists.fedoraproject.org/archives/list/users@lists.fedoraproject.org/message/TCCX357GDN3374RA6H33T7NBLZ44HAVU/)  which links to news [article](https://www.theregister.com/2004/07/30/intel_nocona_nx/) article about release of Xeon E-0 stepping, which (according to intel documentation) provides XD (NX). Presumaby earlier Xeon did not have it.

Comment: That article in the Reg does seem to indicate that there were D-0 stepping Nocona Xeons around, so that would mean x86-64 without NX.  Wow.  Intel also failed to implement `lahf` in long mode in their early CPUs, which is more of an ongoing downside for compiling for x86-64 as a baseline.  Fortunately it's not a very useful instruction most of the time, but not having stuff like `cmpxchg16b` (thanks AMD) and `lahf` (thanks Intel) as part of the true baseline is annoying when it means compilers can't just assume support without using extra options.