# How can a program written in C++ be run on multiple CPU architectures?

Tags: c++, assembly, cpu-architecture, processor

I have a C++ program that I want to compile to assembly, and then assembler will compile it to machine code.

Now, as far as I know, in order to transform assembly code to machine code the assembler needs some kind of table to map assembly instructions to the actual machine instructions.

Which table will the assembler use? Is there a chance that my C++ program won't run on all CPUs, because CPUs use different tables which means that the same machine code will do different things on different CPUs?

Comment: Even assembly code is different depending on architecture. Is there a reason you can't just compile the same source code for each target architecture?

Comment: Are there even compilers which create assembly these days? I thought that this was usually simulated by disassembling the generated code.

Comment: You're describing [LLVM](https://llvm.org). Use that.

Comment: @MSalters That's effectively the same thing.

Comment: "Assembly code" is inherently **non-portable** as in what you're asking for in its most elementary form is actually impossible. C++ compiles directly to a particular ISA (machine architecture), unless you're using something like `clang` which can emit LLVM IR, a pseudo-assembly which can be adapted and compiled again for a target ISA.

Comment: For an introduction into why what you're asking for is inherently contradictory, look at some simple ISA examples like the 6502, the 68000, and the 8088 to see how different they are. The compiler *must* know which architecture to target or it will just emit garbage. A simple look-up table is not going to cut it, the way these chips work is in many cases *fundamentally different*.

Comment: Are you confusing "intermediate code", the output of the first phase of a C++ compiler, with the output of the second phase, a relocatable object file based on the target processor/architecture?  The output of the first phase (the "intermediate code"), could be "retargeted" for different processors/architectures.

Comment: This seems like nearly a duplicate of your previous question, [how does assembler convert from assembly to machine code?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65792675).  The answers there at least imply the answer to this (that machine-code is non-portable, and different ISAs exist.)

Answer (score 5):

The assembler assembles for whatever architecture it has been told to/programed to assemble for.  As the assembly language for each instruction set architecture (ISA) differs, you can only assemble an assembly program written for one architecture for that same architecture.  It is generally not possible to accidentally or intentionally assemble the program for the wrong architecture.

When you use a compiler, the compiler invokes the correct assembler with the correct flags to assemble the assembly code it generated for the architecture you told it to compile for.  The resulting program will only run on processors of the ISA your have compiled it for.  If you want the program to run on processors of a different ISA, you have to compile it for that other ISA.

If your program is poorly written, it is possible that it won't compile or work when compiled for other architectures than the one(s) you developed it for.  Such a program is called an *unportable program.*  However, unless you do weird things or make assumptions about properties of the architecture you are programming for, this is unlikely to happen.

Comment: The reason programs written in C++ can be run on any computer nowadays make me believe that our processors(mine, yours, and mostly everyone's uses the same instruction set architecture) , is that right ?

Comment: @GiorgiLagidze No, that is not right.  There are many architectures in popular use.  Desktop computers and laptops mostly use amd64 (also known as x86-64), smartphones usually use AArch64 (also known as ARM64), servers some times also use SPARC, mainframes use z/Architecture (also known as S390x).  Other architectures like MIPS, RISC-V, ESP32, and ARM32 are also commonly seen.  As I tried to say, the reason why C++ programs can be run on any computer is that you can compile them for any architecture.  However, you do need to compile them separately for each architecture.

Comment: I think what I said is still correct. Since most of the laptops and desktop computers use amd64, whoever wrote the C++ software compiled it for amd64 architecture because he knew that that's the architecture most people use.

Comment: @GiorgiLagidze writing code in c++ means that it can be compiled for many platforms, but the resulting binary, will run only for this platform (OS/CPU) combination. Even a specific CPU architecture like `x86-64` can have instructions that might only be available for newer CPUs (like SEE, …).

Comment: @GiorgiLagidze Certainly that is a point.  However, keep in mind that the program must not only be compiled for a specific architecture, but also for a specific operating system.  So if you want your program to run both on Linux and Windows laptops, you have to compile it twice, once for amd64 Linux and once for amd64 Windows.

Comment: yes, That makes sense, and that's what I meant . So, my almost final question would be this: intel and amd are two different organizations, but do they just follow the same architecture sets ?

Comment: @GiorgiLagidze it really depends on which field you are working. I have coworkers that never bother to compile something for amd64, let alone for a desktop pc or laptop

Comment: @GiorgiLagidze Yes, both Intel and AMD manufacture amd64 compatible processors.  There are other vendors of such processors as well (VIA, Centaur, ...).  Note that both Intel and AMD also manufacture processors for other architectures.

Comment: @GiorgiLagidze You can also target a specific family of x86 instruction set which means the code won't run unless the CPU has those features or extensions. See the [GCC -march options](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/x86-Options.html).

Answer (score 2):

In general what is call assembly is roughly a human readable (text) form of machine code (binary).

As franji1 said in a comment, in general compilers emit an intermediate abstract machine code from the source. And this kind of code can easily (it is intended to) be translated to assembly/machine code.

> I have a C++ program that I want to compile to assembly, and then
> assembler will compile it to machine code.

This is what a compiler is designed to. Compiler is somehow misleading. Compiler can be the "compiler phase" or "compiler toolchain". **compiler phase** is the one that translate your source code to the intermediate abstract form, that then needs to be translated to target assembly/machine code by the **assembler**. **Compilation** is commonly what denotes the whole process from source code to executable machine code.

> Now, as far as I know, in order to transform assembly code to machine
> code the assembler needs some kind of table to map assembly
> instructions to the actual machine instructions.

Roughly yes. This is what a document like [Instruction Set Reference Manual](https://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/manuals/64-ia-32-architectures-software-developer-instruction-set-reference-manual-325383.pdf)  is for: describing how textual form must be translated to byte form.

> Which table will the assembler use?

See document...

> Is there a chance that my C++ program won't run on all CPUs, because
> CPUs use different tables which means that the same machine code will
> do different things on different CPUs?

You have to generate a byte form of your program for each platform (machine/os). A compiler is designed to generate a machine code for a given platform that realizes exactly what your source code specifies. This is why compilers exist, to free you from writing program in assembly (that is very hard to do).